# Is there a way to check if a string has a capital letter and if so change the first letter of the second word to capital in Python?

Tags: python

I've got a piece of code that creates a string in an encoded format and I'm trying to check whether the original message has a capital letter and if so change the number character into a capital letter, here is my current code:

```
characterNumber = 0
  for character in message:
    characterNumberWord = 0
    characterNumber += 1
    if character.isupper():        
      while characterNumberWord != 1:
        characterNumberWord += 1
        string3 += string2.upper()
    else:
      string3 += character
```

For an example imagine message is 'Hello' and string2 is 'jfnmq'. I want the outputted code to be Jfnmq. Fyi this code is a Ceaser Cipher and it changes every second letter.

Comment: Your code is incomplete - not a [mre]. You got NameErrors and IndentationErrors in what youve shown.

Comment: what is the shift in this code, as required by ceaser cipher

Comment: I don't understand why you're asking "is there a way?", when you have written code that uses the specific tools - `isupper()` and `upper()` - that are appropriate to the tasks. It seems that your *actual* question is "why doesn't the code do what I expect it to do?", which means you should start by reading [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Try to think about your logic more clearly. In particular, if you are looking at individual `character` values that are `in message`, then what does `string2` have to do with any of this?

Comment: The shift is 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is to find uppercase characters in `message` and change the corresponding letter in `string2` to uppercase:

```py
message = 'HeLlO'  # uppercase H, L, O
string2 = 'jfnmq'
string3 = []
for l, c in zip(message, string2):
    if l.isupper():
        string3.append(c.upper())
    else:
        string3.append(c)

print(''.join(string3))
# JfNmQ
```

- [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) lets you iterate over multiple sequences together, giving the Nth item from each sequence, as a tuple. So `l` is from `message` and `c` is from `string2`.
- Then check each `l` to see if it's uppercase, and if so, add the uppercased version of the corresponding letter `c` (from `string2`) to the list `string3`. If not upper case, then add the `c` as is.
- The [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) at the end each of the items in the list, the letters in `string3` (which is initialised to a list)

The loop can be shortened to this slightly clearer code:

```py
for l, c in zip(message, string2):
    string3.append(c.upper() if l.isupper() else c)

print(''.join(string3))
```

Or even this one-liner (not-recommended, for lack of readability):

```py
string3 = [c.upper() if l.isupper() else c for l, c in zip(message, string2)]
# or just
''.join(c.upper() if l.isupper() else c for l, c in zip(message, string2))
```

Comment: This seems to work for HeLlO, but if I want to have the message as Hello, is still returns the same thing, JfNmQ.

Comment: Change the intial variable in my code `message = 'Hello'`.

Comment: I have done and it still stays the same, is this a problem with my computer?

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with your computer. I think you're copy-pasting incorrectly. If `message = 'Hello'` then the output is `'Jfnmq'`. I haven't hard-coded a fixed result so if the output doesn't change when you change the input, you're either copy-pasting incorrectly or you're changing the wrong variables.

Comment: Yes, it seems I have a problem in my own code that creates the message, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can use string lower function. Once your string is in all lowercase you can perform your string operations.
e.g.

```
str = "AbCDe"
str = str.lower()
print(str)
# perform your caesar cipher here
```

Comment: I know, but I would like my code to be able to change it then look back at the original message and if a letter is in caps change the new message to have that letter in caps

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the lowercase string with the uppercase one to find the differences. This could be done by bitwise operators. This link may help [String Bitwise operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279134/is-it-possible-to-do-bitwise-operations-on-a-string-in-python)
Or you could iterate through the string to check letters are lower or uppercase with `islower()` and `isupper()` methods:
`[ch.isupper() for ch in 'hello']`

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this.

- I have added some test cases

`def checkForUpper(string):

```
loewrCase = [char for char in string if char.isupper()]
 if len(loewrCase) >= 1:
     print(string.upper())
 else:
     print("No Upper case")


strings=["xxxx","UPPERCASe","UPPERCASE","MIX UPPERloewr"]

for s in strings:
    checkForUpper(s)`
```